# Using php to create a UDP listening "server"

Tags: php, apache, udp

I have a php application that manipulates database and supplying REST API for clients, it works fine.

I was asked to add it capabilities to listen to UDP port, 24/7, and use whatever is submitted through that socket, and add it to the database.

I know how to create a socket with php, and get the data from it. but it's a php page that i need to execute, and the time limit of the script is N seconds.

What is the proper way to run that script as a "listening server" that will execute the relevant code?

I use apache/php on windows.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 1223);

$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);

echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: you will have to create a php daemon,

Comment: Just increase the time limit for this script and just start it once, or use cron for that, or whatever.